# Domains crossed over on digital ocean

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have two domains. exampleone.com and exampletwo.com.

I followed this guide for adding multiple domains on the same server:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

They are both on the same server. Somehow, blog.exampleone.com was created (out of nowhere). and it points to exampletwo.com.

If I click on the site  in google, it shows blog.exampleone.com as the domain, but shows the content for exampletwo.com

How is this happening?

I've looked into the vhost files and everything seems correct.

Here is a sample vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dave@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/exampleone.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.lognano 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This should result in 2 separate sites on the same server. Instead, a blog subdomain was created on one site that points to the content on another site.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to specify the "ServerName" in your vhost file, something like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dave@example.com
    ServerName blog.exampleone.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/exampleone.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.lognano 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

in fact, for each vhost file, you need to specify the ServerName to work properly with your subdomains!

Comment: I did, I was posting that as an example, all of my vhost files have the proper ServerName set